# Spring Boot application works as standalone but class not found when deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have spring boot application , a microservice

I can run it without any problem as Spring boot application

```
mvn clean compile spring-boot:run
```

Now if I try to deploy it in tomcat 9, am getting ClassNotFoundException, shows as if am missing some jar
I tried adding the missing jar for one application , but it keeps coming for newer applications.
There are no steps involved in here, compile ,test as standadlone, then package and deploy to tomcat.

What could be the issue. I guess the actual log is not needed here as the problem seems to be very generic

Comment: What is the tomcat version for the embedded tomcat for the standalone application?

Comment: Do you have Tomcat dependency:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
?

Comment: Please take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Comment: @MohitMutha  Embeded tomcat has no version mentioned. its using the spring-boot version

Comment: @Kamil yes . tomcat starter is present. and the spring boot application is extending the Servlet as well

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani yes.. everything is intact

Comment: @madhairsilence So the log is needed. Please show that

Comment: From the docs `Spring Boot ships by default with Tomcat 9.0.x which supports HTTP/2 out of the box when using JDK 9 or later. Alternatively, HTTP/2 can be used on JDK 8 if the libtcnative library and its dependencies are installed on the host operating system.` So if you are using JDK < 9 you are packaging with Tomcat 8.0 embedded.

Comment: so remove started before deploying in ACTUAL tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is simple, plain and stupid. If you face any similar issue, just  make sure , you are running a similar version of tomcat.

My spring boot application worked fine, when ran using `mvn spring-boot:run` but my actual tomcat server was bit older, so it was missing few libraries.

**Upgrading the tomcat version fixed it**

Answer (score -2):

First of all, Spring boot doesn't require a container, You can execute using java -jar yourspsringboot.war

In your pom, Are you compiling it as war with dependencies? 
If so, verify that under WEB-INF/lib directory. If you not able to find the dependencies in lib directory then it should be the issue.

Comment: "I KNOW" it does not need a container. that why I said i test as standalone and then deploy in tomcat. Deploying in tomcat is a business requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Please include following build tag in your pom. Create new build a deploy. It will work. I also faced this issue.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Updated the message, please check now.

Comment: can you please explain the answer.. how does it solve the missing library